# WordPress Forgets $_POST Fields on Page Reload In Admin Panel to Create Post

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks for your time.

When I attempt to reference a prior set value within the $_POST variable between page loads (as you would in raw PHP) the data is not set.

I am within the context of the Create Post section of the admin panel clicking Publish.

My goal is to refill the fields a user has already specified so as to save them the trouble of re-entering all such text/images/etc. data.

Thanks again for any insight into this!

Comment: wp will do redirects. it's entirely possible that the form page is being loaded via GET, which means $_POST won't be available.

Comment: Does this behavior strike you as a good design decision?

Comment: One word: "Wordpress". "Let's take a blogging platform and turn it into a general purpose CMS that treats EVERYTHING like it's a blog. What could possibly go wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

Your $_POST is empty because there is a redirect in between.

- You are editing at:

  > **http://example.com/wp/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit**
- When you hit publish or save draft the form sends you to:

  > **http://example.com/wp/wp-admin/post.php**

  As you can see in the HTML source code

  > `<form name="post" action="post.php" method="post" id="post">`
- After saving the post, WP redirects you to at:

  > **http://example.com/wp/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit&message=1**

---

You best bet would be to use $_SESSION in your plugin;

```
$_SESSION[ 'my_plugin_POST' ] = $_POST;
```

Comment: I'd like to do this in a way that doesn't break when cookies and/or javascript are disabled.  I was under the impression that $_SESSION only works through cookies, is that correct, and if so, is there another solution?  Thanks very much for the insight, it helps on its own.

Comment: One other quick question - in theory, if I hook the post.php page could I somehow re-save the $_POST variable and forward it to the second level indirection so as to have access to it anyway?

Comment: You can't reach the post edit page unless $_SESSION is available. To answer the question in your 2nd comment, the HTTP protocol is stateless, thus the use of sessions identified by session cookies, sessions allow you to overcome the fact that HTTP is stateless.